# Solving $\lfloor|x+1|-|x|\rfloor\geq x^2$

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I need to solve this inequality:$$\lfloor|x+1|-|x|\rfloor\geq x^2.$$
I checked the domains:

- $x\geq0$ resulted in $[0,1]$.
- $x\leq-1$ resulted in a contradiction.

But when trying to solve the inequality for $-1<x<0$ I get stuck:
$$
\lfloor|x + 1| - |x|\rfloor = \lfloor x + 1 - (-x)\rfloor = \lfloor2x + 1\rfloor \geq x^2,
$$
and I don't how to proceed from here…

Your help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: |x+1| = x+1 when $-1 \le x \le 0$

Comment: @PrashantDattatrey if $-1<x<0$, then $0<x+1$

Comment: i made it correct. try to make graph of $\lfloor 2x+1 \rfloor$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $-1<x<0$, then $$-1<2x+1<1$$
which implies $$\lfloor 2x+1\rfloor =-1\quad\text{or}\quad \lfloor 2x+1\rfloor =0$$

Answer (score 1):

$\lfloor 2x + 1\rfloor$ takes on two possible values for $-1 < x < 0$: $-1$ and $0$.

It takes value $-1$ if $2x + 1 < 0$, which happens when $x < -\frac12$; in this case, $\lfloor 2x + 1\rfloor$ cannot be larger than $x^2$, since $x^2$ is positive and $-1$ is not.

It takes value $0$ if $0 \leq 2x + 1 < 1$, which happens when $x \geq -\frac12$ and $x < 0$. In that case, $\lfloor 2x + 1\rfloor$ cannot be larger than $x^2$, since $x^2$ is positive and $0$ is not.

In other words, there are no solutions to the inequality in the interval $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether $x<-1/2$ or $-1/2\le x$, when $x\in(0,1)$, $\lfloor 2x+1\rfloor$ is $-1$ or $0$ respectively. But over the same interval, $x^2>0$. So there are no solutions if $x\in(0,1)$.